# Convert SQL dataframe into nested Json format in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pyspark-schema

I have sql output I am creating from the parquet file, I want to convert this sql df into the below mentioned format (structType/structField) using pyspark (not scala)

df=self.spark.read.parquet("test.parquet")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_test")

sql = f"""
SELECT id, name, test_id FROM test
"""

[image: |Id | Name |test_id| | 67 |APPLE INC|1027 | | 67 |APPLE INC|1028 | | 67 |APPLE INC|1029 | | 268 |KETO |1127 | | 269 |DAVE |1227 | +-----------------+-----------------------------+]

I want to convert this output into -
"test": [
{
"id": "67",
"name": "APPLE INC",
"test_id":"1027"
},
{
"id": "67",
"name": "APPLE INC",
"test_id":"1028"
},
{
"id": "67",
"name": "APPLE INC",
"test_id":"1029"
},
{
"id": "268",
"name": "KETO INC",
"test_id":"1127"
},
{
"id": "269",
"name": "DAVE INC",
"test_id":"1227"
}
]

Basically the SQL will follow below struct Type and struct Field -
schema = StructType([
StructField(
"test_info",
StructType(
[
StructField("id", StringType(), True),
StructField("name", StringType(), True),
StructField("test_id", StringType(), True),
]),
)
])

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pyspark to_json function to take your dataframe data and convert into a JSON doc, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html

Comment: my input data in not in that format where i can easily convert into json

Comment: @Pooja Could you elaborate?  Your question seemed to indicate you already had it in a dataframe, is that accurate?